# How to parse double values from a String and compare them?

Tags: java

I have this code

```
String info = ...;
info = info +"  "+gst;
```

This `info` stores 3 gst `double` data type values. I want to read these values, compare them and I want to display the largest, the average and total of 3 values.

How can I do it?

Comment: `Double#parseDouble` might be a good start

Comment: There are several ways to do it: 1) Using a `Scanner` and the method `readDouble`. 2) Splitting the `String` and then creating `Double` instance from each new string using `new Double(String)`. 3) Splitting the `Sting` and then creating `BigDecimal` instances from each new string using `new BigDecimal(String)`.

Comment: I did with scanner but only able to read the first value

Comment: "This info stores 3 gst double data type values", what gst mean in this line ?

Comment: thanks for correcting and for your reply

Comment: gst is double data type

Comment: can you give a sample value of info ? just wanted to see how you are storing 3 gst values in info.

Answer (score 0):

first: parse double

```
eg:  String gst_="3";
     Double gst=Double.parseDouble(gst_);
```

Comment: Please describe the question and make a proper search before you ask here.

Comment: Why the underscore in `gst_` ?

Comment: @Shuai Did you understand the question properly? if you did please explain it to me or make edit in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) on a blank space, and then use [Double.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))

```
String [] numbers = info.split(" ");
double total = 0;
for ( String n : numbers ){
    total = total+Double.valueOf(n);
}
//Similar for other things you want to find out.
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

See the code below:
1) Let's say your string info contains double values separated by |.
2) split the 3 values stored in info by using | and store them in string array.
3) Now iterate over the array, convert the string values to double, keep adding up values in sum and place each double value in a double array.
4) Now for find out max, you can use Math.max method which can take two double values.
5) Avg can be found out by sum/array.length i.e. 3 in your case.

Note:- double has rounding off issue, so consider rounding off the double values to particular decimal points.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        //Let say your info contains 3 double values
        //separated by | 
        String info="23.00|43.23|32.22";
        //splitting the info by |
        String[] infoArray=info.split("\\|");
        double sum=0;
        double[] doubleArray=new double[3];
        try{
        int index=0;    
        for(String s: infoArray){
            //converting each value to double
            double val=Double.parseDouble(s);
            sum=sum+val;
            doubleArray[index]=val;
            index++;
        }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            System.out.println("Not a valid double value:"+nfe.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Maximum:"+Math.max(doubleArray[0], Math.max(doubleArray[1], doubleArray[1])));
        System.out.println("sum:"+sum);
        double avg=sum/infoArray.length;
        System.out.println("Average:"+avg);

    }

Output:-
Maximum:43.23
sum:98.44999999999999
Average:32.81666666666666
```